# Реализация слайдера на js

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем, давно хотел научиться делать подобные слайдеры (на главной странице сайта https://www.wireshark.org/). Как реализуется анимация?

Comment: там нету слайдера , паралакс есть , реализуется как обычно - в сети есть уроки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю это поможет. Вероятно новое узнаите.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqYhOkQfdeA